# Was Aristotle aware of Buddha's teachings?

Tags: reference-request, aristotle, buddhism

Are there any references in *Corpus Aristotelicum* to suggest whether Aristotle was aware of Buddhist teachings or Eastern philosophy? Aristotle travelled to Asia Minor at one stage of life, left a voluminious treatise, yet it is interesting there is no shred of evidence alluding to Buddha, Confucius, Lao Tsu or other eastern teachings for a man of such stature. (Research yielded an interesting note of cornocupia of 'facts' whose source is not verified to Aristotle, but should it be then it further begs the question of the lack of reference to Buddha.)  Although Gier has drawn interesting parallels between Aristotle and Buddha in [Experiments in Truth](http://www.class.uidaho.edu/ngier/etabc.pdf), I am interested to know if there has been any reference to this particular area.

Comment: My superficial knowledge tells me that Buddhism tended to travel west (from India to China and Japan). I think the Persian barrier of Zoroastrianism stopped Buddhist influences from getting anywhere close to Asia Minor.

Comment: China and Japan are to the west of india?

Comment: Argh...yes, __east__. '..travel __east__ (from India to China and Japan)' to the __east__. See my question about ['What's the difference between left and right?'](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/666/how-does-one-tell-apart-left-from-right)

Comment: @Mitch: You're probably right but that doesn't mean that the ideas didn't travel, they just didn't take root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical reference in these matters is Thomas McEvilley's brilliant [The Shape of Ancient Thought](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1581152035) (he has a teaser video summarizing some of the findings [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HAiTfOSP_w&feature=gv).)

The short version is: there is considerable evidence of the communication of philosophical ideas between the classical Greek and Indian worlds, in both directions; in terms of Buddhism, this can be most easily seen with Epicureanism, and the connections between Pyrrhonism and Madhyamaka Buddhism.

However, there's no direct evidence that applies to Aristotle.  He may have known of Buddhist teachings, or he may not have.

Comment: IMHO, The closest connections between the two cultures happen when comparing Heraclitus' fragments to the commentaries from Yajnavalkya. They are almost word-for-word equal, under translation.

Comment: McEvilley indeed provides a compelling and enlightening evidence. Although I think the connection between twin Buddha's and 9/11 was a far stretch, it is very much plausible that the whole subject has been one of the greatest "coverup of history".

Comment: To be fair to McEvilley, he doesn't state that there was a connection in any sense between the Bamiyan Buddhas and 9/11, only that the shapes of the absences reminded him of each other, and that the destructions took place/were plotted from precisely that place (Afghanistan) which historically has been the meeting point of East and West.

Comment: What connection between 9/11 and the Bamiyan Buddhas? I can only see that theres two of each - and how can that in anyway be significant?

Comment: The fact were are two of each, next to each other, and that now (or more properly, at the time of the writing) there are two marked absences, where they used to be, having been destroyed (the destruction planned, in both cases, by folks residing in Afghanistan, etc., as described above.)